# (Giamarchi) Physical meaning of $\Psi^\dagger(r)\Psi^\dagger(r+a)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, bosonization

I am currently reading Giamarchi's "Quantum Physics in One Dimension".
The below is the part of the book:

[image]
[image]

Question:
1. Eq. (2.72) of the book defines
$$O_{SU}(r)=\Psi^\dagger(r)\Psi^\dagger(r+a)$$
where $\Psi$ is the fermion field and $a$ is a small vector. The book argues that this describes the tendency of pairing, but why is it? I am not clear about the physical meaning of $O_{SU}(r)$.

2. I think the factor $2i\sin k_Fa$ is missing in (2.76), which was in (2.74). Is this right? Here $\psi_r(x)$ and $\tilde\psi_r(x)$ satisfies
   $$ \psi_r(x)=e^{irk_Fx}\tilde\psi_r(x)=\frac{U_r}{\sqrt{2\pi\alpha}}e^{irk_Fx}e^{-i[r\phi(x)-\theta(x)]}$$
   which is (2.30) of the text.

Comment: You’re probably better making your question 2 a completely separate, new question and removing it from this post